OpenCart 3: weight failure in the сart
There is a problem with the weight in the cart: if the product weight is set to 0 or not set at all, the value 150 grams is displayed. Why, where can I find it, and how can I fix it?
I went through the entire library/cart and catalog/controller/checkout, but I still didn't understand how 0 could turn into another number, because I didn't find anything about it in the code.
OpenCart Version 3.0.3.6 (rs.1)


